# Preventing a python process from being killed due to out of memory

Tags: python, linux, kubernetes

We're running into an issue where python is killed by the OS / k8s due to running out of memory. I see there is the MemoryError exception, but this is never thrown.

I see this is a fairly common problem with `oomkiller`, and getting a proper exception instead of a kill -9 to the face seems nearly impossible.

What are good design patterns to avoid this? We are using a pub/sub based job queue.

- Running each job in a separate process - possible, but stops us from caching expensive model load operations.
- Keeping track of which jobs started but didn't finish, and on the pod encountering the message too many times, ack it as failing - just really quite inefficient on restarts and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up uising a separate process and having to basically re-implement processpool due to it's limitations. See the  medium post below for the solution and resulting open-source package.

https://medium.com/cognite/reporting-a-ml-jobs-failure-due-to-a-hard-crash-or-how-to-tell-people-you-have-died-while-524e62b64840